# How do I enable e-mail alerts in SQLServer?

Tags: email, sql-server

I'm trying to enable e-mail alerts for an operator in SQL Server (2000).
When I try to test the e-mail, I get the following message:

- Error 22022: SQLServerAgent Error: The SQLServerAgent mail session is not running; check the mail profile and/or the SQLServerAgent service startup account in the SQLServerAgent Properties dialog.

When I open [Server].Management.[SQL Server Agent] in Enterprise Manager, The only option that seems at all relevant is the "Mail Session" section; but the "Mail Profile" field (and everything else in the box) has been grayed out.

How do I get those fields enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Outlook on the server, log on as the account you use to run SQL server under and configure Outlook.

See also, [KB311231](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311231).

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the server, click on Properties, then verify that your mail profile shows up on the Server Settings tab.

More info here:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3345091_4/SQL-MAIL-and-SQL-Agent-Mail-using-POP3-and-SMTP.htm